# How to avoid nested loop using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on application where I want to get the user names from employeeList array. Here is I am getting it by using nested loop but this not good practice. Here is my code

```
let _empList = await this.empService.getEmployeesList();
let taskEvents = await this.taskService.renderedTaskGridData(
  _tasksData,
  undefined
);

let associatesList = [];
for (let proj of this.projectsData) {
  let projTasks = [...taskEvents.filter((x) => x.ProjectId === proj.Id)];

  _empList.forEach((x) => {
    projTasks.forEach((y) => {
      y.AssociatedUsersId.forEach((z) => {
        if ((x.Id = z)) {
          associatesList.push(`${x.FirstName} ${x.LastName}`);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I need to get the list using best practice.

Comment: `[...taskEvents.filter(x => x.ProjectId === proj.Id)];` is redundant - `.filter()` returns a new array. No need to make a new array out of that new array.

Comment: What are you trying to extract from here? All users who work on any projects?

Comment: Please show us an example of the arrays you're trying to get the information out of. Otherwise, we're having to guess from the code, which his time-consuming and error-prone.

Comment: `if (x.Id = z) {` **assigns** `z` to `x.Id` and tests the resulting value. You probably wanted `==` or `===`.

Comment: Your current code will include the same employee twice if they're working on two projects/tasks. Is that desired?

Comment: Here this.projectsData are basically projects which are having list of tasks and each task associate with multiple users means task list contains associateUser ids list. Here I am extracting employee list for name whose ids includes in associateUserIds

Comment: Yes @Crwoder you are right user can be associated with multiple tasks

Comment: Basically I want to avoid nested loops to extract user name list.

Comment: "Best practice" is a phrase that poor engineers use to shut down discussion. What specific problem do you want to solve by not using nested loops?

Comment: I am afraid you are right @Ben

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and assume that the problem you are concerned with is the asymptotic complexity (ie - how much your runtime increases relative to the size of your input).

The way I'd solve that would be to make a time space trade-off, like so:

```
let associatesList = [];
const projectIds = new Set(this.projectsData.map((proj) => proj.Id));

const userIds = new Set(
  taskEvents
    .filter((task) => projectIds.has(task.ProjectId))
    .flatMap((event) => event.AssociatedUsersId)
);
const employees = _empList
  .filter((employee) => userIds.has(employee.Id))
  .map((employee) => `${employee.FirstName} ${employee.LastName}`);
```